# how to find out if/why I'm being idled on openshift

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I just upgraded to the bronze plan, but I think I'm either still getting idled every 24 hours, or there's something about haproxy I don't understand.

I have 3 small gears scaled using haproxy, and with no users I'm pretty sure I'm always only using 1. Each morning (~4am Pacific), I visit app-domain.rhcloud.com, and my app is down (error 503). I try again after a couple minutes and it works again. The status page app-domain.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status/ then shows a corresponding uptime.

It's a node app, and there are no errors in nodejs.log, just something about it going down and later coming up:

> DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...
>
> Tue Sep 22 2015 06:07:38 GMT-0400 (EDT): Received SIGTERM -
>   terminating app ...
>
> Tue Sep 22 2015 06:07:38 GMT-0400 (EDT): Node server stopped.
>
> DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
>
> DEBUG:   program 'server.js'
>
> DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/[id]/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
>
> DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
>
> DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
>
> DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
>
> DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
>
> DEBUG: Watching directory
>   '/var/lib/openshift/[id]/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.

Here's the tail of haproxy.log. I don't know how the timestamps work here, so if you need more let me know:

> [WARNING] 263/072454 (223357) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN,
>   reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check
>   duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active,
>   0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>
> [ALERT] 263/072454 (223357) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
>
> [WARNING] 263/072854 (223357) : Server express/local-gear is UP,
>   reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check
>   returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 2ms. 1 active and 0 backup
>   servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
>
> [WARNING] 264/060737 (223357) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for
>   maintenance.
>
> [ALERT] 264/060737 (223357) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
>
> [WARNING] 264/072111 (374009) : config : log format ignored for proxy
>   'stats' since it has no log address.
>
> [WARNING] 264/072111 (374009) : config : log format ignored for proxy
>   'express' since it has no log address.
>
> [WARNING] 264/072111 (374009) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN,
>   reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check
>   duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active,
>   0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>
> [ALERT] 264/072111 (374009) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
>
> [WARNING] 264/072411 (374009) : Server express/local-gear is UP,
>   reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check
>   returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 2ms. 1 active and 0 backup
>   servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is openshift still idling me?

Comment: Log a request at https://developers.openshift.com/contact and we'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

solution!

Based on the comment to my original question, I contacted their support. Turns out it wasn't idling. If anyone else has this problem, it ended up being [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1260204). Support and ops team were helpful and put a patch on my instance in advance of the bugfix rolling out in a couple weeks.